# boolean operators in KQL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I am reading reference for [Keyword Query Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ee558911.aspx) in Sharepoint Search and trying to figure out how AND and OR operators work. I am specifically interested in KQL, not FQL. I am trying to figure out answers to the following questions:

1. What would this query return: `worda wordb`? I understand that documents containing both `worda` and `wordb`. If so then AND keyword seems to be the default. Then why does it exist at all?
2. `worda OR wordb AND wordc` - in this query is `wordb` mandatory or optional?
3. `worda OR wordb wordc` - is `wordc` mandatory here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. using free-text query `worda wordb` AND operator is used by default. If you need OR operator in free-text query you must use it explicitly.
2. In property queries like `propertyA:"worda" propertyB:"wordb"` OR operator is default and AND operator must be used explicitly.
3. Mixing free-text and property queries AND default as well.
4. AND operator has higher priority than OR. `worda OR wordb wordc` is the same as `worda OR wordb AND wordc` and it's the same as `worda OR (wordb AND wordc)`. If you want different behavior you need use `(worda OR wordb) AND wordc`.